# Is there a support for Data protection - storage account on Azure using Terraform?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, terraform-provider-azure

Is there a resource I can use in order to enable Azure's blob data protection objects:
soft delete && versioning?

Comment: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/8268

Comment: Thanks for the comment @ChristianPearce, sorted it for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the property `delete_retention_policy` of the Azure Storage account in `blob_properties` like this example:

```
blob_properties {
    delete_retention_policy {
      days = 7
    }
  }
```

Then it works for the Blob like this:

[image]

Comment: @OmerShliva It seems Terraform does not support the versioning for Blob.

Comment: @OmerShliva See Christian's comment to your question, in the GitHub issue he links to is the solution (https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/8268#issuecomment-704192825)

Comment: @Jannik Yes, that's also a way to solve it. It means you need to use the Azure Template. I more prefer to use the Template directly, not via the Terraform.

Comment: Ok, but then you have some config in Terraform, and some manual. Remember the entire environment should be automated via Terraform for multiple reasons. As an example, it could be Terraform can't delete a resource, if some manually entered config depends on it.